# CardView overlapping each other

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

Hi I have two cardviews each wrapped within a relative layout with the layout_below attribute in use however it does not seem to be working all of the code below is wrapped within a framelayout not sure if this could be an issue. I have tried changing the layout to be linear and that works but I was hoping to have a relative layout instead.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/breakfast_view">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/breakfast_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_heading"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="Breakfast"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/breakfast_view">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/overview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="1dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/info_spliter"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#E0E0E0"
            android:layout_below="@+id/info_tester"/>


    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: don´t exactly know if this is the solution, but if You reference a view inside xml layout, don´t use "@+id". Your second cardview holder (RelativeLayout) must have the attribute "@id/breakfast_view" without the + sign

Comment: You used `layout_below="@+id/breakfast_view"` when you should have used `layout_below="@+id/breakfast_card"` in your second card's wrapper `RelativeLayout`?

Answer (score 0):

The id `info_tester` you refer for the `layout_below` of `info_splitter` is not defined. Even if it was defined, you can only refer to a sibling in the same `RelativeLayout` element. That is to say, your `CardView` elements or any other element you want relatively positioned, should reside in the same `RelativeLayout` element for you to be able to position them relative to each other using `layout_below`.

Answer (score 0):

As you said that you are using a frame layout thats where the problem lies
as each root element in a frame layout is considered as a separate frame so try using a relative layout as a parent like the following or use a single child in the frame layout and then add your views in the child

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AudioPlayerFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/breakfast_view">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/breakfast_card"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/info_heading"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:text="Breakfast"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>
            </RelativeLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/breakfast_view">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/overview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="1dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/info_spliter"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="#E0E0E0" />


            </RelativeLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```